# How do I select an entity from my database using prepared statements

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying check if a certain key exists in the database before i try to add a student whom might have the same key. I have a class called DataBaseHandler which has functions to manipulate the database, The studentAlreadyExist function returns true if the given id is present and false if not. When I try to run the application it gives me this error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
*******
```

Here is my code snippet for testing if a student exist

```
//check if the student exist
public boolean studentAlreadyExists(String id) throws SQLException{
   //first connect to the database;
   connectToDataBase(); 

   selectSQL = "select name from student where idNumber like ?";
   prstmt = con.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
   prstmt.setString(1, id);

   ResultSet rs = prstmt.executeQuery(selectSQL);
   String dbname = null;
   while(rs.next()){

       dbname = rs.getString("name");
   }

    return dbname != null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've prepared it before, you don't have to deliver the queryString again as parameter.

API:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()

Should look like:

```
public boolean studentAlreadyExists(String id) throws SQLException{
   connectToDataBase(); 

   selectSQL = "select name from student where idNumber like ?";
   prstmt = con.prepareStatement();
   prstmt.setString(1, id);

   /* Executes the SQL query in this PreparedStatement object and returns the ResultSet object generated by the query.*/
   ResultSet rs = prstmt.executeQuery();
   String dbname = null;
   while(rs.next()){

       dbname = rs.getString("name");
   }

    return dbname != null;
}
```

Comment: Its now working but here is something odd that is happening. When I check if a student exists in the database it automatically adds another student to my database. I think its linked to the code I created earlier where I was inserting a student to my database. Its inserting the same values I used before

Comment: How do you check if a student exists? Manually e.g. over phpMyAdmin or via java code? Any other functions or code with database handling? This code can't insert or update your database ...

Comment: I have a form with an addStudent panel. When a user presses the addStudentButton on this form , the DataBaseHandler is instantiated inside the actionPerformed function. That is where I call the DataBaseHandler methods like the one above and the one to insert in the database. I commented the part to insert in the database to make sure I was dealing with one problem at a time I will put that part in thye question above

Comment: If the insert statement is commented out, it is impossible that another student will be added in the database. Is there really a new entry or is it just the "System.out.print("Student added");" which is not commented out? Do you have relaunched your application after your last changes? Inner Triggers on your database?

Comment: It is a new entry in my database.n I have to delete it every time I run the code. If I don't it give the error "duplicate key already exists" Maybe I should relaunch my netbeans

Comment: Relaunch your java application, look if all inserts are commented out and please close the database connection after using it. You can get into trouble if not.

Comment: I had an insert query in my connectToDataBase method, its the one that was inserting in my database every time i connected to it

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the `selectSQL` as a parameter (again) when you perform `executeQuery`.